# VisualForce: Add dynamically inputs fields

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have to be able to display, from a custom Object, specific fields.

For example, if the field name contains "_network", I want only to display those fields.

Since at work they will be keeping in creating new fields "_network", I need a system in visualforce that allows me to dynamically display the fields (apex:inputfield) with the constrains described above.

Is this possible by only using visualforce and a controller?

Comment: Yes.Possible through VF page and Controller

Comment: Thank for your answer. Do you happen to have any link reference?

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more? Current requirements are kinda unclear.

Comment: Hi Mahmood, on a visualforce page I want to place the tag "apex:inputfield". The number of "apex:inputfield"'s are unknown, maybe 5 or 6. So I need a system to dynamically place those tags in visualforce.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is for the controller to provide a list of the field API names (that the controller will also have to query):

```
public String fields {
    get {
        // Hard coded list here: build your varying list instead
        return new String[] {'Name', 'Birthdate'};
    }
}

public Contact contact {...}
```

and then use this syntax to reference the relevant SObject fields by the API names:

```
<apex:repeat value="{!fields}" var ="f">
     <apex:inputField value="{!contact[f]}"/>
</apex:repeat>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the exact use case for [`Field Set`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_dynamic_vf_field_sets.htm). You don't even need `Apex`, it is 100% configurable. The example from the docs will work equally well with [`<apex:inputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_inputField.htm) as with [`<apex:outputField>`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm):

> ```
> <apex:page standardController="Contact">
>     <apex:repeat value="{!$ObjectType.Contact.FieldSets.properNames}" var="f"> 
>         <apex:outputText value="{!Contact[f]}" /><br/>
>     </apex:repeat>
> </apex:page>
> ```

If you really want these fields in `Apex` as well, that is of course supported, though in this case I would not follow the example in the docs. Regardless, you can loop through the `FieldSetMember` instances and do whatever you wish with them. For example:

```
List<String> fields = new List<String>();
FieldSet properFields = SObjectType.Contacts.FieldSets.properNames;
for (FieldSetMember member : properFields.getFields())
{
    fields.add(member.getFieldPath());
}
```

Comment: Biggest problem with field sets is that someone has to remember to add the new fields to the fieldset. When delivering to clients I always try to minimize the amount of "Remembering how" they have to do so often go with the code route. I dread the call a year later asking how they add a field to the page. By that time I have forgot how to do it as well lol

Comment: @Eric Yeah but not needing to deploy changes to code is a big win in my book. At the end, `Field Sets` empower your admins more than code. It's up to you to share the keys. You can use `Custom Settings` instead, but they have the same basic pros/cons and are not tailor made for this purpose.

Comment: Agree with the code changes part. Thats is part of my criteria as well when implementing that it has to work without more deployments. In this example adding a field with the `_network` in the name would not require a code change or a fieldset update. Simply adding the field to the object and it would magically appear...This is what is great and not great about the platform.

Comment: Well it's a trade-off of creativity vs. simplicity. You could certainly write a `List Custom Setting` that contains field substrings, then pull any matches from the describe field map. I would rather share the simpler route for the developer in this case, knowing nothing about their skills nor their admin's.